# How to set data for custom attribute in foreach loop Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to set data for custom attribute in foreach loop.My code is here. which is in foreach loop.

```
 echo "<b>".$attribute."</b>"."<br/>";                          
 echo $value."<br/>";  


$attrs = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute); //warrant
$veYstorage = $value;
$avisstorage = $attrs->getSource()->getOptionId($veYstorage); //name in Default Store View
$product->setData($attribute, $avisstorage);
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSource() on boolean in E:\xampp7.0

Comment: have you added $product->save(); in loop ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSource() on boolean in E:\xampp7.0...Actualy i am getting above error.

Comment: Do you have somewhere `$product->save();` in yor code after setting the attributes? If not you should add that. If yes what happens exactly?

Comment: yes i have $product->save(); in end and product is saving but above errors come on attribute set data.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653484/fatal-errorcall-to-a-member-function-getsourceon-a-non-object-in-app-cose-cor?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: That looks like the value for `$attribute` is not a valid `attribute_code` or at least not a select attribute.